# How do I apply loop into node twig template?

Tags: theming, nodes

This is code I am using.

```
<div class="blog-main-content">
  <figure>{{ content.field_article_main_content[0] }}</figure>
  <p class="intro-pera">{{ content.field_article_main_content[1] }}</p>
</div>
```

How can I change that code to make it loop over `content.field_article_main_content`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use code similar to the following one.

```
<div class="blog-main-content">
  {% for key, item in content.field_article_main_content %}
    {% if key == 0 %}
      <figure>{{ content.field_article_main_content[key] }}</figure>
    {% else %}
      <p class="intro-pera">{{ content.field_article_main_content[key] }}</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

If it happens that some values of `key` start with #, then I would use the following code.

```
<div class="blog-main-content">
  {% for key, item in content.field_article_main_content if key|first != '#' %}
    {% if key == 0 %}
      <figure>{{ content.field_article_main_content[key] }}</figure>
    {% else %}
      <p class="intro-pera">{{ content.field_article_main_content[key] }}</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```